# How to find which pin caused an interrupt?

Tags: interrupt, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

How to find which pin caused the interrupt?

```
def handle_interrupt(Pin):
    print(Pin)

int1 = Pin(2, Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
int1.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=handle_interrupt)

int2 = Pin(10, Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
int2.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=handle_interrupt)
```

Output:

```
Pin(2, mode=IN, pull=PULL_UP)
```

or:

```
Pin(10, mode=IN, pull=PULL_UP)
```

I can use different handlers, or convert the class to a string and split, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Why is using different handlers crazy? That is the normal solution since each interrupt usually means executing different code. If they are both going through the same code, then what does it matter which one fired.

Comment: @Bib Edited my question, the interrupt is coming from external port expanders and I would like to use only one handler to check which port expander I need to scan to find the pressed button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
def handle_interrupt(irq):
    print(irq)

int1 = Pin(2, Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
int1.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=lambda a:handle_interrupt(2))

int2 = Pin(10, Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
int2.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING, handler=lambda a:handle_interrupt(10))
```